# Insert failed - persistent minimongo 2

Tags: javascript, meteor

I am using [meteor-persistent-minimongo2](https://github.com/frozeman/meteor-persistent-minimongo2) to store my data offline. Everything is working fine apart from an error that I am getting. Not able to figure out the real cause.

```
No message (1)
insert failed: getErrorObject — aldeed_collection2-core.js:489
doValidate — aldeed_collection2-core.js:471
(anonymous function) — aldeed_collection2-core.js:223
(anonymous function) — frozeman_persistent-minimongo2.js:2518
(anonymous function) — frozeman_persistent-minimongo2.js:477
(anonymous function) — meteor.js:1195
promiseReactionJob
```

[image]
Please help in rectifying this error.

Comment: Update to meteor 1.6.1, I am not even getting stack trace.

Comment: Please include the code where you created the persistent instance along with the collection it's watching and an example db query to the collection from your app.